# How can I relatively rotate lines connected at pivot points?

Tags: animation, javafx, rotation, pivot

### Skeletal Movement

Hi I have been trying to create a skeleton made of **Joints** and **Bones**. The skeleton is done in JavaFX using circles and lines. I have manage to connect the lines (bones) at pivot points (joints). Given two pivot points it is possible to rotate a bone around its parent joint. What I am trying to achieve is for Example:

Given that there are 3 bones connected to each other at pivot points Bone **A**, **B** and **C** if lets say bone **A** is rotated around its pivot point bone **B** and **C** should move relative to bone **A** while maintaining their respective positions.  If bone **B** is rotated bone **C** should follow.

**Here are some images showing the desired effect**

Shows how the bones are originally position before rotating bone **B**

[image: Original bones position]

Shows how the bones should be position after rotating bone **B**

[image: Position after moving bone **B**]

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to calculate the values in order to make this possible. I have been looking around for similar problems for a while with no luck. I was hesitant to ask the question. I hope my question was clear enough. All comments and help is deeply appreciated Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try putting bones B and C in a group, and rotate that group around bone B's pivot point. Then create another group containing bone A and the first group, and make that larger group rotate about bone A's pivot.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I think I understand the approach. Still wonder if there is some other way since there are scenarios where the skeletons may be complex and the more less nodes used the better. The bones are created by drawing them with the mouse. and attaching joints to them =)

Comment: That will make it more complex; I think the only other option is going to be using bindings with pretty complicated computations. Without actually trying to write the app, it's hard to know for sure, but my instinct is that creating `Group`s will be simpler in the end. You can probably find an object model that makes this work reasonably elegantly (`BoneSet` extends `Group` and contains one bone (`Line`) and zero or one additional `BoneSet`s, or something?)

Comment: @James_D I will definitely give your approach a go. It sounds like it is worth a try. Thank you very much for your time. =). I ll post back if any luck

Comment: @James_D Hey man just wanted to say that your method worked! Thanks a bunch for helping me out =D

Comment: Excellent. If you can create a reasonably simple example, you can post it as an answer to your own question. It may help other users who have similar questions in the future.

Comment: Thank you will do as you suggested once done =)